# Apache Spark mapPartition strange behavior (lazy evaluation?)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to log the execution time of each mapPartition operation on a RDD using a code like this (in Scala):

```
rdd.mapPartitions{partition =>
   val startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
   result = partition.map{element =>
      [...]
   }
   val endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
   logger.info("Partition time "+(startTime-endTime)+ "ms")
   result
}
```

The problem is that it logs the "partition time" immediately, before it start to execute the map operation, so I always obtain a time like 2 ms.

I noticed it by watching the Spark Web UI, in the log file the row regarding the execution time appears immediately after the task started, not at the end as expected.

Someone is able to explain me why? Inside the mapPartitions the code should be executed linearly, or I am wrong?

Thanks

Regards
Luca

Comment: Transformations are lazily evaluated.

Comment: Ok, thanks! 
I solved putting a "result.size" before the endTime.
I thought that by default the map inside the mapPartitions being a Scala operation was not lazy.

Comment: @philantrovert no this is not the reason, map inside mapPartitions is not a Spark transformation, this is pure scala-related

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I see, thanks!

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, in fact I had noticed that using result.size was not the right solution, because the result of mapPartition was empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`partitions` inside of `mapPartitions` is an `Iterator[Row]`, and an `Iterator` is  evaluated lazily in Scala (i.e. when the Iterator is consumed). This has nothing to to with Spark's lazy evauation!

Calling `partitions.size` will trigger the evaluation of your mapping, but will consume the Iterator (because it's only iterable once). An example

```
val it = Iterator(1,2,3)
it.size // 3
it.isEmpty // true
```

What you can do is to convert the Iterator to an non-lazy collection type:

```
rdd.mapPartitions{partition =>
   val startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
   result = partition.map{element =>
      [...]
   }.toVector // now the statements are evaluated
   val endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis
   logger.info("Partition time "+(startTime-endTime)+ "ms")
   result.toIterator
}
```

EDIT: Note that you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or even `System.nanoTime()`) instead of using `Calendar`.